# Two identical boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Im a beginner coder to R and am trying to use the tidyverse package with the Cherry Blossom Run run17 data set to create grouped boxplots so that I can compare the net times it took in minutes for each sex to complete the 10 Mile race and the 5K race. However, I am having issues creating this as I thought my code would do this however it produces 2 identical boxplots which have incorrect medians and I was hoping if anyone could point me in the right direction as to what I have done wrong?

```
run17 %>%
  filter(event == "10 Mile", na.omit(run17)) %>%
  ggplot(data = run17_min, mapping = aes(sex, net_sec/60, fill = sex), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Gender", y = "Time (minutes)", title = "10 Mile Times by Gender")

run_17 %>%
  filter(event == "5K", na.omit(run17)) %>%
  ggplot(data = run17_min, mapping = aes(sex, net_sec/60, fill = sex), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Gender", y= "Time (minutes)", title = "5K Times by Gender")

run17 %>% filter(event == "10 Mile", sex == "F") %>%
summarise(med = median(net_sec/60))
run17 %>% filter(event == "10 Mile", sex == "M") %>%
summarise(med = median(net_sec/60))
run17 %>% filter(event == "5K", sex == "F", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
summarise(med = median(net_sec/60))
run17 %>% filter(event == "5K", sex == "M") %>%
summarise(med = median(net_sec/60))
```

This is my R code so far and I believed that this would produce two different boxplots however it produces two identical ones with incorrect medians as can be proven through the summary statistics in the chunk. I have also tried to remove the NA values but for some reason it does not seem to be working as well.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Remove `data = run17_min` from the `ggplot()` calls. This is causing ggplot to use the unfiltered data, rather than the filtered data passed by the pipe.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `na.omit()`? If you want to remove `NA` values for a particular variable, say `net_sec`, then use `!is.na(net_sec)` instead. If you want to remove rows that are `NA` for _any_ variable, use `drop_na()` — eg, `... filter(event == "10 Mile") %>% drop_na() %>% ...`

Comment: @zephryl why recommend `drop_na` over `na.omit`? I normally don't have any problems with `na.omit`.

Comment: @GregorThomas right -- my point was really just that OP shouldn't be using `na.omit()` inside `filter()`. But they could certainly use `%>% na.omit() %>%` instead of `%>% drop_na() %>%`.